# Swift Class as Parameter to Instantiate Later

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following Swift code. My goal is to be able to pass in the type or class of either `FirstItem` or `SecondItem` into the `Manager` to be able to instantiate later on (by calling the `createItem` function).

```
protocol CustomItem {
    static func instantiate() -> CustomItem
}
class FirstItem: CustomItem {
    static func instantiate() -> CustomItem {
        return FirstItem()
    }
}
class SecondItem: CustomItem {
    static func instantiate() -> CustomItem {
        return SecondItem()
    }
}
class Manager {
    var itemClass: CustomItem

    func createItem() {
        let itemInstance = itemClass.instantiate()
    }

    init(itemClass: CustomItem) {
        self.itemClass = itemClass
    }
}
let manager = Manager(itemClass: FirstItem)
```

How can I fix the code above to allow for this so that the manager accepts the class itself instead of an instance of the class.

Comment: `instantiate` is rather useless. Just make an initializer part of the protocol.

Comment: @Alexander Fair enough. But the point of this isn't really the instantiate function. And I'm assuming there are situations where that function could be more complicated.

Comment: I know, hense why this was a comment, and not an answer. Also, depending on your needs (which I know nothing about), perhaps taking a "CustomItemGenerator" closure (of type `(SomeInput1, SomeInput2, ...) -> CustomItem`) might be worth considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the parameter type that you are accepting in the init function to `CustomItem.Type` and changing the value you are passing in to `FirstItem.self` this works. For example changing the code to something like the following should work.

```
protocol CustomItem {
    static func instantiate() -> CustomItem
}
class FirstItem: CustomItem {
    static func instantiate() -> CustomItem {
        return FirstItem()
    }
}
class SecondItem: CustomItem {
    static func instantiate() -> CustomItem {
        return SecondItem()
    }
}
class Manager {
    var itemClass: CustomItem.Type

    func createItem() {
        let itemInstance = itemClass.instantiate()
    }

    init(itemClass: CustomItem.Type) {
        self.itemClass = itemClass
    }
}
let manager = Manager(itemClass: FirstItem.self)
```